# Loading new Ubuntu on old HP

Tags: software-installation, hp

trying to load Ubuntu 14.04 on an older HP ze4500 using a flash drive as the loading device.  The computer has recently had a full wipe done on it.  It  begins fine then freezes less than halfway thru several attempted installations, never actually reaching the "Install" menu. I have tried several variations including disabling the APIC via the GRUB screen.  Any suggestions plz?

Comment: When you say "never actually reaching the 'Install' menu" you mean that it's not booting up fully? Could you try booting with the boot option "nosplash" and see if there are any errors shown? If it's freezing it's probably a kernel panic, and the last message you see should be relevant.

Comment: or try `nomodeset`

Comment: Went with "nomodeset" (no "nosplash" option).

Comment: Responds "ali mixer 1 creating error.  ALI15X3 not detected, module not inserted"  Also mentioned upgrading my BIOS

Answer (score 0):

try using the netboot installer http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso

hope this helps!
cheers
whitaar